# How do I say "Fix the way I look like"?

Tags: phrase-request, sentence-request

I'll explain the phrase I am looking for using this example. Imagine that I put on the T-shirt, jeans and jacket. I'm going to walk with my friend. and suddenly she says: "your sleeves look scruffy, "fix" them". so I'm looking for a term which means something like "to remove a position of any piece of clothing in the previous one, also make it look tidy and attractive again"...

Comment: Are you asking for a term to describe that act when you do it your self  (or the other person does it for you), or how to ask the other person to fix it (for example, what needs fixing is behind you so you can't see it)?  But the word "fix" is commonly used for things like you describe -- making something look right that isn't.

Comment: the act when I do it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you're about to go into a meeting or an interview and you want to make sure you don't have a mustard stain on your shirt or that one of your buttons is not unbuttoned or something like that.

You could say:

> I took a quick look in the mirror to check my appearance.
>
> I checked myself in the mirror to see how I looked.

Now, if you do happen to spot something amiss, you could say:

> I needed to fix *how I looked* before going into the meeting.
>
> I needed to fix *the way I looked* before going into the meeting.

English often uses  clauses like that in place of specific nouns.